# Web API Post returns 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How should one carry out CRUD operations on a SQL Server database using C#?

For example, let's say there is a DB table `Employees` with these columns:

```
EmployeeID, FirstName, PostalCode
```

and I wish to post a new employee with info to that database. What would be an efficient method to accomplish this?

My current `HttpPost`:

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void AddEmployee (Employee employee)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Server=.\servername;Database=Northwind;User ID=Username;Password=password;";

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID,FirstName,PostalCode) Values (@EmployeeID, @FirstName, @Zip)";

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", employee.EmployeeID);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", employee.FirstName);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", employee.Zip);

            myConnection.Open();
            int rowInserted = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `Employee` model:

```
namespace API.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public int Zip { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I test my API with Fiddler with the following input:

```
{ "EmployeeID":91, "FirstName":"Vader", "Zip":94221}
```

I get this error:

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

and nothing is inserted into the database.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

`WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
namespace API
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The raw error message generated, as per request:

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Expires: -1
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>
> X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcYW1lc2tvXGRvY3VtZW50c1x2aXN1YWwgc3R1ZGlvIDIwMTVcUHJvamVjdHNcQVBJXEFQSVxhcGlcRW1wbG95ZWVzXEFkZEVtcGxveWVl?=
>
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> Date: Fri, 22 Jul 2016 15:33:06 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 986
>
> {"Message":"The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.",
>
> "ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Employee' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.",
>
> "ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
>
> "StackTrace":"   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Comment: What's your `Content-Type` header? `application/json`?

Comment: Yes. My program then runs on `localhost:55239`, and I access my `POST` with `localhost:55239/api/Employees/AddEmployee`.

Comment: Can you post your RouteConfig?

Comment: Posted my `WebApiConfig` that generates in VisualStudio. I just realized that I must have deleted the `RouteConfig.cs` that VS creates. I'll try to add it back and see what happens.

Comment: Please add the raw request posted through Fiddler.

Comment: Well, that wasn't what I asked for (is asked the request) but it is clear @JamieR suspected it already: you aren't sending a `Content-Type` header: `The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.`

Comment: My apologies for misinterpreting the requested info. This is my first foray into APIs and using Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

How are you passing the JSON Input? It needs to be through the request body with with request type application/json

you can specify you route as

"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

and then when calling the API url would be

http://localhost:63433/api/Employees/AddEmployee

notice Controller is not part of the URL

In the request body put

{ "EmployeeID":91, "FirstName":"Vader", "Zip":94221}

make the request type as Post 
and request body as application/json

you may test your api from a client tool like postman see screen

[PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARkv5.png)

If you can post ur client code may be I can check it.